# workaround for two dimensional Arrays in django

Tags: arrays, django

I would like to make a Ingredientslist for recipies(model named articles) and therefore need to assign unique values to Ingredients out of a Many to Many Infredient list.

I know that there is no straight forward way to implement a two dimensional array in django but I hope someone here has had this issue and knows a workaround.

Here I have my models being part of this issue:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    kcal = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(800)], blank=True, default=0)
    carbs = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(99)], blank=True, default=0)
    protein = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(99)], blank=True, default=0)
    fat = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(99)], blank=True, default=0)


class Article(models.Model):
    banner = models.ImageField(null=True, default='dashboard-BG.jpg')
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, default='Unnamed')
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, default='Unnamed')
    article_body = models.CharField(max_length=4000, null=False, default='Lorem Ipsum')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    ingredientList = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=False)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, blank=True)

    kcal = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(3000)], null=True, blank=True)
    carbs = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(3000)], null=True, blank=True)
    protein = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(3000)], null=True, blank=True)
    fat = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(3000)], null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        ingredients = self.ingredients
        totalCalories = 0
        totalCarbs = 0
        totalProtein = 0
        totalFat = 0

        for i in ingredients:
            totalCalories += i.kcal
            totalCarbs += i.carbs
            totalProtein += i.protein
            totalFat += i.fat
            if i == 0:
                return

        self.kcal = totalCalories
        self.carbs = totalCarbs
        self.protein = totalProtein
        self.fat = totalFat
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

The 'two dimensional array should be the ingredients model field. Many ingredients having a specific unique amount for this recipe.

Thx for all the answers in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django, models are representations of fields in SQL datatables. You could look into the JSONField type. This Field will hold any form of JSON data, basically a python dictionary. You could have one key for the ingredient and one key for the amount. Hope this helps!

Comment: oh yes thx. I added that. to my post under the code

Comment: I am new to json field. How can I assign values to a json over that admin view. I guess that would be tricky in a way, right?

Comment: Over admin view, just use JSON format. {"key":"value, "key1":"value1"}. In Python, you can assign dictionaries to JSON fields because they are the same format.